# python: query mongodb database to find a specific value under a unknown field

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb

I am using python to generate a mongodb database collection and I need to find some specific values from the database, the document is like:

```
{
"_id":ObjectId(215454541245),
"category":food
"venues":{"Thai Restaurant":251, "KFC":124, "Chinese Restaurant":21,.....}
}
```

My question is that, I want to query this database and find all venues which have a value smaller than 200, so in my example, "KFC" and "Chinese Restaurant" will be returned from this query.

Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: Can you change your schema? Using the restaurant name as a key in the `venues` object is bad design because it doesn't support making these types of queries.

Comment: Ohh I get what you mean, you mean "venues" is replaced by a specific restaurant name like "KFC" so it's easy to query, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can change your schema it would be much easier to issue queries against your collection. As it is, having dynamic values as your keys is considered a bad design pattern with MongoDB as they are extremely difficult to query.

A recommended approach would be to follow an embedded model like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("553799187174b8c402151d06"),
    "category": "food",
    "venues": [
        {
            "name": "Thai Restaurant",
            "value": 251
        },
        {
            "name": "KFC",
            "value": 124
        },
        {
            "name": "Chinese Restaurant",
            "value": 21
        }
    ]
}
```

Thus with this structure you could then issue the query to find all venues which have a value smaller than 200:

```
db.collection.findOne({"venues.value": { "$lt": 200 } }, 
    {
        "venues": { "$elemMatch": { "value": { "$lt": 200 } } },
        "_id": 0 
    });
```

This will return the result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "venues" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "KFC",
            "value" : 124
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @gladys0313 No worries :-) You could read more on Data Modelling [**here**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) to get a good understanding on the above.